# How to fix issue with String capitalization

Tags: swift, string

My goal is quiet simple:

[image]

2 capitalized letters from a `Date()`.

```
func getWeekday(booking: ClientBooking) {

    let formatter = CoreServices.getDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEEEE"

    let weekday = formatter.string(from: booking.date)

    print("weekday = \(weekday)")
    print("weekday.capitalized = \(weekday.capitalized)")

    self.weekdayLabel.text = weekday.capitalized

}
```

The problem. The 2 print statements result in:

```
weekday = Fr
weekday.capitalized = Fr
```

Same does the `label.text`. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

(Expected of course would be `FR`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`NSString.capitalized` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416784-capitalized):

> A capitalized string is a string with the first character in each word changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.

I think you'd be happier with one of these properties mentioned in the “See Also” section of the same page:

> ```
> var uppercased: String
> ```
>
> An uppercase representation of the string.
>
> ```
> var localizedUppercase: String
> ```
>
> Returns a version of the string with all letters converted to uppercase, taking into account the current locale.

Comment: oh well. thank you very much... no wonder it didn't work... thank you. 6mins till accept